# Selectively "pass" commands onto the shell/program if certain programs are running

Tags: linux, shell, tmux

Is there a way for tmux to "pass" its control commands (C-A x) to the program running in the pane if a certain program is indeed running?

Comment: I suppose `tmux`is similar to `screen` in this respect and a quick screening of its manpage supports this assumption: You can pass the control key C-A to the running program by hitting it twice, so `C-A C-A x` goes to `emacs` or whatsoever as `C-A x`. Is your question ,,How to save this extra key stroke?''

Comment: @mpy - yes, how to save this extra key stroke, but only if a certain program is running in the current pane shell.